# Display message when user clicks submit button in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When a user is clicking `submit` button, we would like to display a message of `Please wait...'`. A `onclick` is added to the view file:

```
<%= f.button :submit, t('Save'), :class => BUTTONS_CLS['action'],  onclick: "console.log('Please wait....');" %>
```

Here is the `html` source out of the above:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="console.log('Please wait....');" class="btn btn-default btn btn-md btn-hover btn-primary" value="保存" name="commit">
```

But nothing is happening when clicking the `submit` button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

console.log would only log a message in the browser console, It would not show anything user visible.  Rails does have builtin support for changing the message shown on the button and disabling it while the submit happens

```
<%= f.button :submit, t('Save'), :class => BUTTONS_CLS['action'],  data: { disable_with: 'Please wait....' } %>
```

If you want more than that you'll need to describe exactly what you mean by "display a message of Please wait... "

Comment: When a user clicking `submit` button to upload a file, a message of "Please wait..." shows on the screen (just like a status bar)

Comment: Nothing happens with `data: {disable-with: 'Please wait...'}`. The html source is `<input type="submit" data-disable-with="Please wait...." class="btn btn-default btn btn-md btn-hover btn-primary" value="保存" name="commit">`

Comment: hmm -- with data-disable-with and jquery_ujs loaded it should change the text on the button and disable it, unless you have some other JS event handler overriding/blocking the UJS handler

Answer (score 1):

You can display a message or progress bar with the [NProgress](https://github.com/caarlos0/nprogress-rails) gem. There are other gems available e.g. [PACE](https://github.com/yovu/pace-rails).